# What's the best way to remove code in production builds?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, servlets

I have the requirement to execute some (serverside) code in hosted mode only. The perfect solution would be to not even compile the code into production builds. Whats the best way to accomplish this (using GWT 2.5 with eclipse)?

Comment: Split it out into its own `.jar`, which you don't deploy?

Comment: If what you're asking for is to not compile specific lines of code from files, that's not reasonably possible in Java. (You can run the C preprocessor over anything but it will at the very least confuse your IDE.)

Answer (score 0):

How do you build for production and are you able to separate that code out to a class or classes? If the answers are "Maven" and "yes" I would look into using a Maven profile and appropriate exclusions when gwt-compile'ing and packaging.

There is also the [`GWT.isScript()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#isScript%28%29) which returns `true` in hosted mode and false otherwise. Then at least your code won't be executed in the production build.

Cheers,

Comment: Both, GWT.isScript() and GWT.isProdMode() always return false if called at the server. There's already an issue about it: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6148 
Any other ideas how to determine a release build from a hosted mode execution or debug build?